# Is there a case when a C function can be defined within a header file?

Tags: c, function

Is there a case when a function can be defined within a header file? I was told by person whose opinion I respect that there are cases when a function can be defined in a header file included by multiple C source files. However, I could not find any. Just confirm, I define the function in-line in a header file but that also did not work. I will but have not found any answers yet. There is no practical requirement as such. I just wanted to see if there is some part of the C standard that I don't know of which will allow this. Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but **only** if it is declared as `static inline`.

Functions that are declared simply as `inline` behave exactly like functions that are defined with no modifiers, except that they may be inlined within the translation unit that they're defined as `inline` in. They still have global scope, so including them in a header file will result in errors, as the function will be multiply defined.

`static inline` functions, on the other hand, do not have global scope — they only exist where they are used, more in line (ha ha) with the way you probably think of inline functions. As such, they're appropriate for use in header files.

Comment: The "static" keyword in "static inline" is harmful in the situation
where a "static inline" function gets included and compiled in N
different files and does not get inlined. In this situation, one would
typically want the N copies of this function to get merged into one,
to avoid code bloat. But the "static" keyword prevents that, forcing
the linker to not merge these redundant functions.

Comment: @Mr.32 No, it does not. The `inline` modifier makes the function indeterminately resolve to either the `static` function or the `extern` one of the same name, even if the `extern` one is never defined. All non-inlined calls map to the same `extern` function in C, and if this isn't defined, having a non-inlined call produces a link error.

Answer (score 2):

No C function should not be defined in Header files.

`function declaration` can go in Header files.

But `function definition` should not ever go in header files.

**Reason:**

If function defination goes in header files then header will be included by multifple c files and when they are going to compile they will give error for multi defination of same files.

---

`static inline function can` be defined in Header files.

But that should not be used because

The "static" keyword in "static inline" is harmful in the situation
where a "static inline" function gets included and compiled in N
different files and does not get inlined. In this situation, one would
typically want the N copies of this function to get merged into one,
to avoid code bloat. But the "static" keyword prevents that, forcing
the linker to not merge these redundant functions.

Comment: multiple definition error can be overcome by `static` or `static inline` and `inline` specification.

Comment: Then multiple file will have theri own copy of static function in scope of include files. This design is technically wrong.

Comment: @Jayesh read my Edit in my answer. why we should not use static inline

Comment: A function defined as `static inline` is hidden from the linker. There will never be anything to merge; it will never appear in non-inlined form, unless you include an `extern` definition in one TU. Taking the address of a `static inline` function with no `extern` counterpart will fail with a link error. This is required by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note to the answers/discussion on inline functions, I believe that theoretically one could define a function in a header in the same way as in a normal .c file, *providing the header was only included once and in single location*.

Though I'm not sure if the standard explicitly forbids this or not, it follows from the idea that the contents of a header file are essentially being copied and pasted into the top of the source file in which it is included from which point of view, there would be no issue.

Comment: The standard doesn't really care about this (it behaves in a well-defined fashion), but it's a poor practice — the whole point of a header file is to be reusable. If you can only include it once, why bother?

Comment: Agreed, it's poor practice and should not be done, but the OP specifically stated that the question was not aimed at a practical requirement *only* curiosity, so the answer is yes, it can be done, even without `static inline`. Whether it *should* be done or not is a different question

Comment: good point. Although it is poor practice it's helpful to know what the standard defines.